# Android: Google play services not working on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

I had to format my Windows laptop so I copied the SDK folder (because it's about 30 GB large) and i pasted it in the same place on the new Windows copy.

Now when I start Android Studio and SDK Manager everything looks fine and all tools & packages appear as downloaded, but when I start an emulator to test my app, it says `Get Google Play Services` which I already have in my `gradle` as follows:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

It was working fine on the old Windows machine but now it refuses to detect `Google Play Services`.

Also the emulator is very slow, it used to be very fast on the old Windows machine.

What am i missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change "Project Build Traget"  to Google API by default it is to the api level you have upgraded to.

Comment: You have included Play services library with your app. Now if you look on your physical phone app list, you'll find its Google Play services app counterpart, which is missing from your emulator. What you include with your app is just means to connect to the Play services app.

Comment: This answer solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Google Play Services` app is missing on the *emulator*. The library is required only to compile projects against the Google Play Services APIs'.

As per the reference documentation at [**Setting Up Google Play Services**](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html):

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target.

So what you need to do is use the *Google APIs* as the target SDK setting.

Comment: Yes i'm using a Lollipop Emulator (5.0), it should come with Google API in it, but it always says `Get Google Play Services`

Comment: I think i should delete and re-download them, i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Download [Google Play Services 7.0](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-7-0-99-1809214-836-android-apk-download/) and install it in your emulator either via adb shell or simply by dragging and dropping.

I recommend GenyMotion emulators as they are comparatively fast and easy to access.

Comment: Drag and drop into an Android emulator (not Genymotion)?  Never seen that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to the system image I selected during device creation. The default option was the `UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox`. This would simply crash anytime I tried opening it or I'd get the "Google Play Services has stopped" message.

[image]

I fixed it by using the regular `UpsideDownCake` system image.