# Can not run Google Play service on emulator (need to update Google Play service)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I've tried to install Google Play on the emulator. I've followed the instruction from  [Google Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Using ADV manager it seems ok, devices are targeting  Google API version 22, but when I run my image I always have an "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services"

[image]

My test program works fine on a real device

The dependencies includes this:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

I've tried to manually add the Google Play apk:

```
> adb install -r com.google.android.gms-7.3.29_\(1866531-038\)-7329038-minAPI9.apk 
4503 KB/s (37113767 bytes in 8.048s)
   pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.gms-7.3.29_(1866531-038)-7329038-minAPI9.apk
```

So is there a way to check emulator is running with Google Play services? If no, how to solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429727/android-google-play-services-not-working-on-the-emulator/29430240#29430240

Comment: -> it is not supposed what happens when you create a device using adv with the binary including google API? If not, how do you know which apk to install (here it's 7.0.0 while in my case it's 7.3.0)

Comment: @AbhishekDabral I've tried to manually install the latest apk, no change

Comment: try with genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Comment: Google API version 22 emulator has fU  Google Play's updater(i don't have link to bug now but i'm sure that i found it few days ago) .... use Google API version 21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to create an emulator with Google API 21 (and not 22) and it worked... See @selvin remarks

Answer (score 3):

Please install "Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image" API 22 to access Google Play services on emulator.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue, so i changed google play services version in my build.gradle file from 8.1.0 to 7.8.0. I think the Problem is because your application is using higher version of google play services then the version which is installed on emulator. Above is the work around, don't know the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I deleted the google play services in the SDK manager (see pic). And then re-installed it. Then try restarting the SAME emulator and hopefully the app works!
[image: Delete Google Play Services, and then re-install it]

This is a very annoying issue. It can also be solved with downgrading your build.gradle file as mentioned by Fenil, where the x.x.x have changed by now.