# Google Play service not working on my emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting an error that google play services not installed in you device when I am trying to run my code on my android emulator. Although the code is woking fine on my physical android device.

Comment: which emulator you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Google play services not working on the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429727/android-google-play-services-not-working-on-the-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

You should use an emulator with `google API` like attached screenshot:

[image]

Those with `(Google APIs)` tag beside them have google play service installed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your device image does not come with Play Sotre services installed.

Create another device emulator with an image that the Play Sotre services are already installed. Those images will have a checked icon in `Play Store` column:

[image: Device image with Play Store Service]

Answer (score 0):

Use geny motion. Its much better than default emulators.

You can download one from [here](https://www.genymotion.com/)